# Renaming iOS project in Xcode changes device to 'My Mac'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a universal iOS project intended for the iPad. My client has come up with the App's final name and I need to rename my project. When I do (following the instructions within Xcode), it changes the deployment device to 'My Mac' and (obviously) won't run. I can't find a way of changing it without restoring a back-up - but I do need to rename the project. I've done this loads of times before without a problem, but it is the first time since upgrading to Xcode 6.3 (6D570). Has anyone encountered this and got a solution?

Comment: Do you need to rename the project? Or just the app name? You can change the app name in its Info.plist, under the CFBundleDisplayName key.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I just meant the App name. I'll try what you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: It's almost worked - it takes the spaces out though!

Comment: Works with spaces here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't add a comment. You must create a new scheme, and then the project should work. I added screenshots. My link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lhzfphhtzupcl6e/AAByUiZPpX4ZKEjFde4YsjLra?dl=0